# Is my Internet fast enough for Xbox Live?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, xbox360

Is my WiFi Internet fast enough for playing on Xbox Live?

Down: 1.15Mb/s
Up: 0.06Mb/s
Ping: 879ms

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I had done a search on "Xbox" to see if it was even asked on this site, and I saw around 250 results, so I thought it would be okay.

Comment: ping to what? ping of 879ms means nothing without any frame of reference. It is also not an accurate measure of anything relating to speed or latency if you are running over multiple networks. Speedtest results are also not very useful without a frame of reference. You'd get better and more accurate test results with SNMP. In any case, bandwidth is not a measure of speed, it is a measure of how much can be pushed through a line at once, so your question should be more on the lines of "If I play X game on Xbox live, will x.x/x.x throughput suffice?"

Comment: @MaQleod I think it is safe to assume if his ping to anywhere is 879ms then it is a bad ping, and other pings will be similar.  High pings are not good for live services such as XBL.  That is the main reason XBL does not work with most satellite internet connections. Also, this seems a legit networking question to me, voting to reopen.

Comment: @typoknig, I disagree, the destination is important as you need to know what networks you are traversing or have tests to multiple destinations. Granted, this is probably high latency due to utilization as 95% of the customers I troubleshoot have that problem, but sometimes it is a routing problem that may affect only a specific destination or geographical location. He may have 43 ms ping times to google.com and can still have 879 ms to somewhere else. It is not uncommon at all and it is very important to test.

Comment: I am very grateful that people are still paying attention to this even though it is closed, and thank you @typoknig for the vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think so, you would be lagging a lot.  Your download speed is bad enough, but your upload speed is very sub-par and your ping is horrible.  Sorry to be bearer of bad news :(

I was in the same boat as you probably are, living in the sticks where there is no high speed data.  The desire to have Xbox Live drove eventually lead me to a long range wireless solution.  I'll spare you the details unless you want them, but basically the solution for me was getting two wireless routers that ran DD-WRT, getting two high gain yagi antennas, and setting up a wireless bridge between me and the closest place that did have high speed internet 2 miles away.  I have recently upgraded my routers and antennas, total investment price for current setup is about $500, plus I pay for the internet at the residence where I have the first router/antenna beaming me signal.  This allows me to get full bandwidth and has been working for me for over 5 years with no problems.

Comment: ... So wait, how bad are we talking?  I've heard of people playing with Down as bad as 1Mbs and Up as bad as 700Kbs, but nothing about ping time...

Comment: And if I had a direct line from my router or modem to the Xbox, would it be faster?

Comment: Yeah, you could connect with 1 Mbps for your download speed, but that would still be bad.  I had a 1.5 Mbps connection for awhile and that caused me to lag in games such as Halo.  700 Kbps up would be fine for you upload speed, but you wrote you had 0.06 Mbps, which roughly 60 Kbps... Big difference.  Also a direct connection to your Xbox (as opposed to wireless) isn't your problem.  Your bottle neck is your internet connection, not your LAN.